# Difference between svnrdump dump & svnadmin dump

Tags: svn, dump, svnadmin, svndump

I need a dump of a svn repository. I found two solutions

> `svnrdump dump`

And

> `svnadmin dump`

`svnrdump dump` is the same of `svnadmin dump`?

If not, what are the differences between these two commands ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`svnrdump` generates the same dump as `svnadmin dump`.  According to [the red book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnrdump):

> The svnrdump program is, to put it simply, essentially just network-aware flavors of the svnadmin dump and svnadmin load subcommands, rolled up into a separate program.

The only difference between the two is that `svnadmin dump` operates on a file path to the repository (i.e. it should be run on the same server) whereas `svnrdump` accepts a remote repository URL.

An example `svnadmin dump` command:

```
svnadmin dump C:\repositories\repo1 > repo1.svndump
```

An example `svnrdump` command:

```
svnrdump dump http://example.com/svn/repo1 > repo1.svndump
```

Comment: FYI `svnrdump` is in SVN 1.7+ **AND** if you're on mac you only get `svnrdump` after installing *xcode command line* tools and you'll find `svnrdump` at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/` source: http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 10):

The answer from Patrick is mostly correct, However the dumps provided are NOT the same.
**svnrdump** by default creates a delta encoded dump file. While **svnadmin dump** does not.
**svnadmin dump** needs the switch **--deltas** to produce matching dumps.