# Migrating huge SVN repository to GIT with minimum freeze time on the SVN repositories

Tags: git, svn, gitlab, git-svn

I am working on a project that has been running from quite some time now. It is hosted on SVN. It has 24K revisions. Someone in the organisation thought (and I agree) it would be great if we could migrate all the projects in the organisation from SVN to GIT. Its easy said than done. Our project is a very critical to maintaining inventories and is due in production next quarter. The timeline for migration is set to December end. This means that we neither have a wait time nor the luxury of freezing the SVN repository. I decided to take following approach:

1. Create a dump of the current repository using `svnrdump`. This took around 3Hrs.
2. Load the dump to the local `svn` repository. This took around 12Hrs.
3. Convert local `svn` repositories to `git` using `git svn clone`. This takes more than 73Hrs.
4. Push this `git` repository to the `remote`.

Now while these steps were being performed, some new commits were made to the existing remote `SVN` repository. Is there a way, I could merge these new changes to the new remote `git` repository. It is worth noting that we want to retain all the commit histories from SVN. If there is a way to do this, it would mean that we will have to freeze the current remote SVN only for a couple of hours. I would also like to mention that our new `git` repository is hosted on `gitlab`. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the [differences between `svnrdump` and `svndump`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131309/difference-between-svnrdump-dump-svnadmin-dump), check first if a locally done (directly on the server) `svndump` (if you do have access to said server) would not be faster.

Then, for the few commits/revisions created concurrently, you can do an [`svnrdump --incremental`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnrdump.html#svn.ref.svnrdump.sw.incremental).

> Dump a revision or revision range only as a diff against the previous revision, instead of the default, which is begin a dumped revision range with a complete expansion of all contents of the repository as of that revision.

You can convert that into its own Git repository, fetch it into your current Git repo, and rebase/cherry-pick the orphan branch on top of your normal Git branch, to keep the history. ([See an example here](https://github.com/githubtraining/example-rebase-orphan-branch))

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since its a corporate SVN, the developers do not have a direct console access to the server hosting SVN. That was the reason I had to use `svnrdump` instead of `svndump`

Answer (score 0):

JFYI: SubGit in "sync" mode will give you automatic mirroring of changes and *zero downtime*

Comment: I thought about SubGit, but it is not free (except for a one-time svn to Git migration, I believe). However, after seeing https://subgit.com/pricing, a mirroring should be possible, at least for 30 days, as part of a trial period.